# Finding raster files in a directory that contain noData pixels/cells ... ArcGIS and Python

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, arcgis-10.6, nodata

I am trying to find a way of looping through Rasters in a directory, (a collection of individual tiff images in a folder) and selecting by name only those rasters that contain noData values and passing those TIFF file names into a list. By inspection most of the TIFF files do not have noData values in them. However a number do and I would like to be able to achieve this programmatically. I am trying to do this using arcpy / ArcGIS tools and modules

My code so far is below, but it is not picking out the rasters where I know there are no data values

What is wrong?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\myRasters\...'

rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()

incompleteRasters = []

for raster in rasterList:
    rasterObj = arcpy.Raster(raster)
    print(rasterObj.name)

    if rasterObj.noDataValue == True:
        incompleteRasters.append(rasterObj)           
        print("NoData Value: %s \n" %noData, "in ", rasterObj.name)
    else:
        print("all ok")

print('All', len(rasterList), 'tifs have been checked')
```

Answer (score 2):

What you script is doing at the moment is just testing if the raster's *noDataValue* is set to True, it's not actually checking if there are noData values, but what value has been *specified to represent* noData.

I think you need to use the [GetRasterProperties](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-raster-properties.htm) function and call out the ANYNODATA property.

Try this edited version of your script:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\myRasters\...'

rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()

incompleteRasters = []

for raster in rasterList:
    rasterObj = arcpy.Raster(raster)
    print(rasterObj.name)

    # Get the raster properties (this returns a string, not an integer)
    noDataFound = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(rasterObj, "ANYNODATA").getOutput(0)

    if noDataFound == "1":
        incompleteRasters.append(rasterObj)           
        print("NoData Value: %s \n" %noData, "in ", rasterObj.name)
    else:
        print("all ok")

print('All', len(rasterList), 'tifs have been checked')
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. This is doing exactly what I wanted. I was heading down the path of trying something with arcpy.Describe(raster) .. but your suggestion is much slicker.. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows and you have GDAL installed and you just need to get the job done fast you could try this one-liner from command line:

```
for /f  %i in ('dir /b *.tif') do gdalinfo %i |find "NoData"
```

The output looks like this:

```
>gdalinfo File1.tif   | find "NoData"
>gdalinfo File2.tif   | find "NoData"
  NoData Value=255
>gdalinfo File3.tif   | find "NoData"
```

File2.tif has nodata set to value 255, files File1.tif and File3.tif do not have nodata.